# AngularJS ng-click change color within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code that lists out items in a table from a database. The click function toggles the cells between green and red

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="logs-table col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">

            <tr>              
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Seed</th>
                <th>Division</th>                
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="team in Pool">
                <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': started, 'btn-success': !started}" ng-click="inc()">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
                <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
                <td>{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
            </tr> 

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My click function is below

```
 $scope.inc = function () { $scope.started = !$scope.started }
```

The only problem is that this is changing all of the cells in the first column. I'm thinking i need to pass a parameter in my click function, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use the `started` value in your controller, you don't really need to define a function.

You could use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to initialize an array keeping track of the `started` value for each team.

Something like this:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="team in Pool" ng-init="started = []">
            <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': started[$index], 'btn-success': !started[$index]}" ng-click="started[$index] = !started[$index]">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
            <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
            <td>{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Somehow cleaner would be if there was a `started` property on every team instance:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="team in Pool">
            <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': team.started, 'btn-success': !team.started}" ng-click="team.started = !team.started">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
            <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
            <td>{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing a parameter into your function will help.  Currently you have a `$scope` level variable (`$scope.started`) which selects your css ng-class.  You probably want a team-by-team property.  To do this, you should refer to the actual `team` object from within your ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in Pool">
    <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': started, 'btn-success': !team.started}" ng-click="inc(team)">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
    <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
    <td>{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
</tr>
```

And in your javascript:

```
$scope.inc = function (team) { team.started = !team.started; }
```

Now that your are using the actual individual object (`team`) from your ng-repeat, everything should work fine.